# Scala: Find and update one element in a list

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz

I am trying to find an elegant way to do:

```
val l = List(1,2,3)

val (item, idx) = l.zipWithIndex.find(predicate)

val updatedItem = updating(item)

l.update(idx, updatedItem)
```

Can I do all in one operation ? Find the item, if it exist replace with updated value and keep it in place.

I could do:

```
l.map{ i => 
  if (predicate(i)) {
     updating(i)
  } else {
     i
  }
}
```

but that's pretty ugly.

The other complexity is the fact that I want to update only the first element which match `predicate` .

**Edit: Attempt:**

```
implicit class UpdateList[A](l: List[A]) {
  def filterMap(p: A => Boolean)(update: A => A): List[A] = {
    l.map(a => if (p(a)) update(a) else a)
  }

  def updateFirst(p: A => Boolean)(update: A => A): List[A] = {
    val found = l.zipWithIndex.find { case (item, _) => p(item) }
    found match {
      case Some((item, idx)) => l.updated(idx, update(item))
      case None => l
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just realized the issue haha. I only want to do it on the first item found.

Comment: Given that I can only think in having a mutable variable to track if an update already was made and do the map with `if (!alreadyUpdated && predicate(i))` - you can encapsulate everything in a method to don't expose the mutable variable. For a completely immutable solution, I would use a `foldLeft` in which you accumulate the new **List** _(backwards)_ and the flag of `alreadyUpdated`, after the fold you may extract the **List** and then reverse it - however it will have complexity **2O(N)** _(two iterations)_ and may be too complex. Not sure if there is a better way, that is why I dont answer

Comment: then I feel than my `updateFirst` method is the best so far ?

Comment: Wonay, IMHO no. The intention is very clear that is a point! - but it does a lot of iterations _(**O(3N)** in case the first element is near to the end)_ and creates one extra intermediate collection. If you're sure the collections will be small and the first item will be near the beginning it may not be so bad.
Aki, I don't believe that is a good idea, because he/she needs the element too, thus it will need to call apply with that index again which will result in another iteration - but will make the intention more clear!, which is a point! Other idea would be to use Vector instead of List.

Comment: How would that work with a vector ?

Answer (score 3):

You can avoid `.zipWithIndex()` by using `.indexWhere()`.

To improve complexity, use `Vector` so that `l(idx)` becomes effectively constant time.

```
val l = Vector(1,2,3)
val idx = l.indexWhere(predicate)
val updatedItem = updating(l(idx))
l.updated(idx, updatedItem)
```

Reason for using `scala.collection.immutable.Vector` rather than `List`:
Scala's List is a linked list, which means data are access in O(n) time. Scala's Vector is indexed, meaning data can be read from any point in effectively constant time.

You may also consider mutable collections if you're modifying just one element in a very large collection.

https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html

Comment: That's not better than the author's code because `l(idx)` is `O(N)`

Comment: Would you mind editing your solution with Vector ? Would any of the code change or just the performances ?

Comment: Wonay as Leighton already said the code will no change, but its performance will be sightly better. However be aware that `Vectors` [are not as great as one expects](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html#vectors-are-ok)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know any way to make this in one pass of the collection without using a mutable variable. With two passes you can do it using `foldLeft` as in:

```
def updateFirst[A](list:List[A])(predicate:A => Boolean, newValue:A):List[A] = {
   list.foldLeft((List.empty[A], predicate))((acc, it) => {acc match {
     case (nl,pr) => if (pr(it)) (newValue::nl, _ => false) else (it::nl, pr)
   }})._1.reverse
}
```

The idea is that `foldLeft` allows passing additional data through iteration. In this particular implementation I change the predicate to the fixed one that always returns `false`. Unfortunately you can't build a `List` from the head in an efficient way so this requires another pass for `reverse`.

I believe it is obvious how to do it using a combination of `map` and `var`

**Note**: performance of the `List.map` is the same as of a single pass over the list only because internally the standard library is mutable. Particularly the cons class `::` is declared as

```
final case class ::[B](override val head: B, private[scala] var tl: List[B]) extends List[B] {
```

so `tl` is actually a `var` and this is exploited by the `map` implementation to build a list from the head in an efficient way. The field is `private[scala]` so you can't use the same trick from outside of the standard library. Unfortunately I don't see any other API call that allows to use this feature to reduce the complexity of your problem to a single pass.